# SQL Server split function with two delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have a string with coordinates like: '0 0, 1 2, 3 4, 0 0' and I want to split it into two columns x and y.

Result I want to receive:

[image]

I found a solution for T-SQL but unfortunately SQL Server does not have a split function encoded, I also found some functions to do that but only for one kind of separator and I can't 'upgrade' by myself, this is my very beginning with SQL.

Please, help ;)

Comment: This is out of sql's scope. It doens't have that function because you're not supposed to need one... Use a programming language to achieve that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772227/tsql-nested-split-parse-of-string-into-table-multiple-concatenated-tagvalue-i/28773089#28773089

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this answer here... you should be able to tweak it for your needs:

[TSQL: Nested split/parse of string into table (multiple concatenated Tag:Value in one string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772227/tsql-nested-split-parse-of-string-into-table-multiple-concatenated-tagvalue-i/28773089#28773089)

Answer (score 0):

To get that done, you need first to split the data into rows from `,` and then split all the rows into two columns.

To split the data into rows you can use for example the [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) function by Jeff Moden.

Once you have the rows, then you can locate the space with charindex, and take the parts using left and substring functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here I use a recursive CTE

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca938/9)**

```
;WITH tmp(id, DataItem, coord) as (
    SELECT id, 
           LEFT(coord, CHARINDEX(', ', coord + ', ')-1),
           STUFF(coord, 1, CHARINDEX(', ', coord + ', ')+1 , '')
    FROM coordinates    
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 
           LEFT(coord, CHARINDEX(', ', coord + ', ')-1),
           STUFF(coord, 1, CHARINDEX(', ', coord +', ')+1, '')
    FROM tmp
    WHERE coord > ''
)
SELECT id, 
      DataItem, 
      coord, 
      SUBSTRING(DataItem, 1, CASE CHARINDEX(' ', DataItem) WHEN 0 THEN LEN(DataItem) ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', DataItem)-1 END) AS X,
      SUBSTRING(DataItem, CASE CHARINDEX(' ', DataItem) WHEN 0 THEN LEN(DataItem)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', DataItem)+1 END, 1000) AS Y
FROM tmp
ORDER BY id
```

OUTPUT

```
| id | DataItem |         coord | X | Y |
|----|----------|---------------|---|---|
|  1 |      0 0 | 1 2, 3 4, 0 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  1 |      1 2 |      3 4, 0 0 | 1 | 2 |
|  1 |      3 4 |           0 0 | 3 | 4 |
|  1 |      0 0 |               | 0 | 0 |
```