# SQL: find character in string, create new fields at each instance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a large table (>10,000 rows) where one field is a "blob" of mashed together information that I need to extract... Anyone know how I can create a new field at every instance of a character?

```
What I have for each report_id is like:
```

[image: [*plz click* ugly blob of data]]

```
And what I need for each id is like:
```

[image: [*plz click* neatly ordered fields]]

Each report has different information & lengths, but all are delimited by 3 asterisks "***"... How can I break the blob for each id field of variable length characters preceding ":" to be column headers & the variable length characters after ":" to be row content, breaking at each instance of "***"?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks :)
*I'm using MS SQL Server 2016 (64 bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? (The SSMS version is irrelevant for the features available in the database engine)

Comment: There are a lot of string splitters that will do this... you'd do it in two steps. First, create a CTE that does the initial string split on the *** delimiters, and then a second CTE that uses the output of the first and splits on ":"... how you map the string to a schema column depends on a number of factors so we'd need more information here. Are these a fixed set of values on the left of the colon that you know ahead of time? Or is it more dynamic and variable?

Comment: Here's code to do the dual delimiter string split... so it'll parse apart your blob into the data you need. You can then use CASE statements to map data to the columns in insert or update statements as appropriate, but I can't help there without more info, like schema details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772227/tsql-nested-split-parse-of-string-into-table-multiple-concatenated-tagvalue-i/28773089#28773089

Comment: I would suggest using LINQPad to parse out the data, then you can use SSMS to modify the table, then use SQL or LINQPad to put the data in the new fields.