# looking to split/parse out text in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

i have a dataset in SQL server which has a column i wish to parse out.
Looking to get positive and negative values onto different columns and also if there is a multiplier to put in different column against the value it is to be multiplied against.

EG of how the column looks that i want to parse out

```
create table #temped (
    originalstring varchar(100)
)

insert into #temped
    select 'SUM([S720]) - SUM([S719]) * 2 + SUM([S719])'

insert into #temped
    select 'SUM([R382]) + SUM([R989])'

insert into #temped
    select 'SUM([S716]) * .295'
```

I would like to put the positive values in one column, the negative in another and the multiplier in another. the multiplier should be on the same row as the one it is to be multiplied against.
Example output of the first insert above would be

```
Col_positive Col_Neg  Multiplier
S720         S719     2
S719
```

So far i've tried charindex and split string with also doublesplit which i found here: [TSQL: Nested split/parse of string into table (multiple concatenated Tag:Value in one string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772227/tsql-nested-split-parse-of-string-into-table-multiple-concatenated-tagvalue-i/28773089#28773089)

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate problem for SQL.  You might consider Python or some other scripting language.

Comment: I would reconsider what you are doing completely. Your data structure seems to be tragically flawed here.